# Represent first 8 characters of the string as hex numbers separated by spaces

Tags: perl

I need to represent first 8 characters of the string as hex numbers separated by spaces.

For example:
**"This is the test!"** converts to **"54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20"**

I use the following code to do it. Is there better(simpler) way to do it in Perl?

```
my $hex = unpack( "H16", $string );

my $hexOut = "";
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < length($hex) ; $i += 2 )
{
    $hexOut .= substr( $hex, $i, 2 ) . " ";
}
$hexOut = substr( $hexOut, 0, -1 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't resist submitting a Perl one-liner!

```
my $string = "This is a test";
print(join(' ', unpack("(A2)*", unpack( "H16", $string ))) . "\n");
```

Comment: Isn't the second `unpack` unnecessary? `print(join(' ', unpack('(H2)8', $string)), "\n")` has the same output.

Answer (score 1):

If you split on null, you get a list of bytes. Then just print them in hexadecimal.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = shift // 'This is the test!';

my @bytes = split //, $string;

for my $i (0..7) {
    printf "%02X ", ord $bytes[$i];
}
print "\n";
```

But if you really want characters rather than bytes, then unpack.

```
my @chars = unpack "C0U*", $string;

for my $i (0..7) {
    printf "%02X ", $chars[$i];
}
print "\n";
```

For the test string, it's the same

```
$ ./leon01.pl
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 
54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20
```

but in general, it's not

```
$ ./leon01.pl 'A Møøse once bit my sister.'
41 20 4D C3 B8 C3 B8 73 
41 20 4D F8 F8 73 65 20 

$ ./leon01.pl '① ② ③ ④ ⑤ ⑥ ⑦ ⑧ ⑨ ⑩'
E2 91 A0 20 E2 91 A1 20 
2460 20 2461 20 2462 20 2463 20
```

Comment: splitting to `''` is faster (in general, I don't think that's an issue here)

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you decide if this is better or not.  Just another way to do it. ;-)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
$string    = "This is the test!";
$strLength = length($string);

@bytes = unpack(A2 x $strLength,unpack("H16",$string));
print "@bytes\n";

# Also could change it back to a string w/spaces:
$pretty = join(" ",@bytes);
print $pretty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $string = "This is the test!";
my $hex_string = sprintf("%vx", substr($string, 0, 8));
$hex_string =~ y/./ /;
print $hex_string, "\n";
```

(The v modifier is a perl-specific extension to printf formats, introduced sometime in 5.8.x IIRC.)